# Alternative to nofollow: custom 302 url shortener?

Tags: seo, redirects, http, nofollow

Here's the scenario: lots of blogging platforms make it tedious to insert `nofollow` into links within the post content. I.e., you need to edit the html, format it correctly, etc.

I have a client who posts lots of content with links that should be nofollow'ed, and I thought of a novel way to handle this, since the blogging platform they're using makes it hard:

I install a URL shortener web app on the client's domain. The shortener works as normal, *except* it redirects via 302 instead of 301. The pagerank will therefore stay at the shortener's domain, and not flow on to the target site.

Part 2: In order to get the pagerank to collect meaningfully, say on the site's home page, the shortened URLs would be generated like this: `/link?12345` instead of `/link/12345`. And then, the path `/link` would 301 to the home page. This way, the id is a param, not a path element. And thus, all the incoming shortened links are going to one path, which transfers pagerank to the home page.

So that's my idea. I wanted to see if anybody could find problems with it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm totally missing "part 2", couild you explain better?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be over-complicating the solution. You could use Thaya Kareeson's [nofollow.js](http://omninoggin.com/web-development/using-jquery-to-easily-dofollownofollow-links/) which uses the following line to easily nofollow links:-

```
$(".insert-your-css-class-here a").attr("rel", "nofollow");
```

You can replace your css class or simply do

```
$("a").attr("rel", "nofollow");
```

Obviously you'll need to wrap the above in a function or follow the implementation tutorial linked to above.

Comment: but are you sure that adding nofollow via Javascript would impact the PR in the same way as a nofollow written inside the HTML? I know Google reads Javascript, but are you sure Google also minds nofollow added via Javascript?!

Comment: @MarcoDemaio you can test this very easily using the fetch as googlebot tool in Google webmaster tools. Since Matt Cutts has confirmed that the bot does execute javascript, I would suspect you'll be fine - but obviously you need to test what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Google's alter ego Matt Cutts, but what does it make you think that because you are using `/link?12345` all the PR will flow to the HOME PAGE?!

I think Google sees `/link?12345` as just a different url than `/link/` path so the PR won't flow to `/link/` nor to HOME PAGE.

Moroever **IMHO**, i think your spaghetti links could punish your site as a site that is attempting to cheat the system. I know you are not doing it for black hat SEO, but how would Google know it.

I would try to fix the Blogging platform, I think it should be enough to track the function that renders the page article contents. Then using a simple PHP string subtituion or a `preg_replace` you could add all the needed nofollow attribute to each `"<a href..."` strings just before they are rendered.